# Lubuntu 14.04 Problem starting lxsession-default-apps

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I have one problem, I can't execute `lxsession-default-apps` on Lubuntu 14.04 because I get because said to me "The database is updating, please wait"

If I try to run `lxsession-default-apps`, I get this error:

```
 ** Message: utils.vala:30: config_path_directory: /home/USER/.config/lxsession-default-apps
 ** Message: desktop-files-backend.vala:171: test config_path: /home/USER/.config/lxsession-default-apps/settings.conf
 ** Message: desktop-files-backend.vala:237: Scanning folder: /usr/share/applications
 ** Message: desktop-files-backend.vala:278: Start scanning


 ** Message: desktop-files-backend.vala:257: Scanning folder: /usr/share/app-install/desktop
 ** Message: desktop-files-backend.vala:278: Start scanning


 Error: list_files failed: No such file or directory
 ** Message: desktop-files-backend.vala:333: Finishing scanning


 ** Message: desktop-files-backend.vala:189: Signal finish scanning with mode: write
 ** Message: desktop-files-backend.vala:333: Finishing scanning
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The /usr/share/app-install directory is created when you install the `app-install-data` package. This package provides metadata about applications that is used by the Ubuntu Software Center and (in your case) the Lubuntu Software Center.

I don't know why this isn't a dependency for `lxsession-default-apps`, but it resolves "No such file" error and gets it to load.